# Warning - Integer operation result is out of range in c

Tags: c, gcc

I'm using RVCT compiler to compile this code in C (relevant section here):

```
static void Test (void)
{
     unsigned long regVal;
     regVal |= (UINT32)(    (0x1 << 31)     |
                            (0x1 << 26)     |
                             0x3E);
}
```

When compiling the code, I receive the following warning Warning:
" #61-D: integer operation result is  out of range".

I would like to understand what to change in order to avoid the warning.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should consider initializing `regVal` first or assigning it just with the `=` operator instead of the `|=` operator.

Comment: @patrickvacek while that's certainly a valid point, I don't think that's the main point of this question.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that compiler, but usually, that variable will take a random value, it will NOT be initialized to 0.
Change your |= to = to avoid.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen, I know, that's why it's a comment and not an answer. It was intended to be friendly advice.

Answer (score 9):

Due to integer promotion rules, the inner expression (i.e. before the `(UINT32)` cast) is treated as `signed int`. Therefore, `0x1 << 31` is `0x80000000`, which is a negative signed integer, thus resulting in the warning. To fix, you can force the shifts to be unsigned by appending 'U' to the hex constants, like `0x1U`.

```
 regVal |= (UINT32)(    (0x1U << 31)     |
                        (0x1U << 26)     |
                         0x3EU);
```

This will force all of the shifts and bitwise ORs to be unsigned, which should get rid of the warning (and also removes the need for the `(UINT32)` cast, since it's already unsigned).

Answer (score 1):

The compiler overflow warning is correct, because the expression 1<<31 represents a signed int. To avoid the warning, explicitly define the constant 0x1 as an unsigned value using the U postfix. For example:

```
unsigned long regVal;
regVal |= (UINT32)(    (0x1U << 31)     |
                        (0x1 << 26)     |
                         0x3E);
```